# Will Google Tango Unity SDK (Camera Motion Tracking part) be extended to other phones?

Tags: google-project-tango

Would the camera tracking functionality would of Google Tango Unity SDK become compatible to IOS?

Answer (score 1):

Project Tango SDK are developed based on Android. I don't think it is compatible to ios. 
also The SDK right now only works for Project Tango Device only.
other Android device also won't work

Answer (score 0):

IOS is not going to happen, since this is native to Android. But to expand on your question, google is trying to make this into a mass market consumer product, but it's a really slow process. This is on of the most recent and helpful news stories I found on the topic 
http://www.engadget.com/2015/05/29/google-qualcomm-project-tango-phone/